# Como creo pipeline en python-social-auth, llene datos en un formulario?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

Necesito hacer un registro usando python-social-auth y Django, que use los datos de Facebook para pre llenar algunos campos del formulario de creación de usuarios.

Alguien sabe como hacerlo?

Comment: No lo hagas en el formulario, haz el mapeo en una vista o en el modelo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo solucione agregando una vista parcial 'pipeline' el cual envía a la vista del registro los datos de Facebook por get 'querystring', allí los trataba y luego continuo con el pipeline de python social auth.